# getting 'module has no attribute' from matplotlib and noise

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-import, noise

I'm using Python 3.7.4, Windows 10 with matplotlib 3.2.1, image 1.5.31, noise 1.2.2, pillow 7.1.2 and am trying to get this code to work

```
import noise
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

shape = (50,50)
scale = 100.0
octaves = 6
persistence = 0.5
lacunarity = 2.0

world = np.zeros(shape)
for i in range(shape[0]):
    for j in range(shape[1]):
        world[i][j] = noise.pnoise2(i/scale,
                                    j/scale,
                                    octaves=octaves,
                                    persistence=persistence,
                                    lacunarity=lacunarity,
                                    repeatx=1024,
                                    repeaty=1024,
                                    base=42)

plt.imshow(world,cmap='terrain')
```

When I run it I get

```
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot'
```

and if I change the import of matplotlib (with or without the Agg line) to

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get

```
File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 93, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py)
```

Ive also been getting

```
AttributeError: module 'noise' has no attribute 'pnoise2'
```

I can't tell if this is an interpreter issue or what

Comment: Have you named a file `matplotlib.py` somewhere? Or `noise.py`

Comment: @roganjosh I just noticed something, could stuff in C:\program files\miniconda3\lib\site-packages be conflicting with C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

btw it seems it was a problem with conda packages conflicting with non-conda packages. Seems to work now when I uninstalled conda.